# INSERT results into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, outer-apply

Is it possible to INSERT the result of the following query into new table

```
SELECT
    O.[full name], 
    O.[EID], 
    O.[Loc],
    GL.*
FROM 
    [dbo].[team] O 
OUTER APPLY 
    [dbo].[fngetlocdetail] (O.[eWorkCity]) GL
```

As standalone it works but I cannot `INSERT` results these results into a new table. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: How did you try inserting ? post that as well. What are the columns `[dbo].[fngetlocdetail]` will return ?

Comment: function returns, long/lat, city, country data

Comment: Can you post the `Insert` query you have tried and the error message

Answer (score 3):

Just use `into`:

```
select O.[full name], O.[EID], O.[Loc], GL.*
into #NewTable
from [dbo].[team] O outer apply
     [dbo].[fngetlocdetail](O.[eWorkCity]) GL;
```

You should specify the column names for `GL`.  As @Prdp aptly points out, this will fail if the column names in `GL` duplicate one of the other names.

Comment: This may throw error if `[dbo].[fngetlocdetail]` returns same column name as the ones present in column list. But the possibility is very less just a information to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the [Select Into](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) statement?

```
SELECT 
    column_name(s)
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Why dont you add that error message so we can see it and help instead of just vaguely referencing the failure